# 2 data validation condition in 1 cell

Tags: excel, validation

I have a cell that I need the user to enter a decimal number between 0 and 1, also at the same time, I need to truncate the number to only allow 6 decimal places.

I can use the Data Validation Button to implement either one of these two, but how can I implement both of them at the same time?

Comment: You can use data validation to truncate values!?

Comment: @CallumDA I know I can truncate the value to 6 decimal place, how can I for the number to be within 0 and 1 at the same time?

Comment: Use the maximum and minimum limits allowed.

Comment: It was actually a question. Data validation *validates* data, it can't change it. So I'm pretty sure it's not truncating your data. It might be checking if your data has fewer than six decimal places?

Comment: @CallumDA truncate can be done by use custom validation with TRUNC function.

Comment: @SolarMike how do I limit the decimal to only 6 decimal places?

Comment: I understand, but there is a difference between truncating a number automatically and only allowing 6 decimal places. You will only be able to do the latter

Comment: I tested with min limit 0.000000 and max limit 0.999999 - seems to work.

Comment: @SolarMike, that will allow values between those limits with more than 6 decimal places

Comment: @CallumDA So I have just seen, with more testing - so the other solutions look good now... Yours and Scott's

Comment: @CallumDA,  Thank you both for the comments and answers, which helped me finding a way to make it work.

Comment: @SolarMike,Thank you both for the comments and answers, which helped me finding a way to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following to make it work, this is done with Data Validation and Custom Validation Criteria.
`=A1=IF(AND(A1<=1,A1>=0),TRUNC(A1,6),"ERROR")`
This will check for both condition, then return the value with 6 decimal places, instead of True/False.

Comment: I don't see how this does anything differently to the previous answers? It won't return the value with 6 decimal places. Try it with `0.1234567` it won't change to `0.123456`, it will just throw an error... as I've been explaining

Answer (score 1):

Use custom formula:

```
=AND(A1<=1,A1>=0,LEN(A1)<=8)
```

Comment: Good use of `LEN`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I understand now. As I said in my comment, you cannot change the value in the cell (i.e. truncate it), but you can limit inputs to those with 6 decimal places or fewer. Validate with custom formula:

```
=AND(TRUNC(A1,6)=A1,A1>=0,A1<=1)
```

for validating cell `A1`.